# Open href image link in a Lightbox

Tags: javascript

This is the actual structure i have

```
<a class="magnific-popup" href="images/traitements/trait8.webp">
    <img class="img-responsive image" src="images/traitements/8.webp" alt="traitement 8">
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="text">
            <img aria-hidden="true" src="images/plus.svg" class="plus-icon">
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

When i click on the < a> i want the image link in the href to open in a lightbox using only javascript no jquery.

Any help ? :)

Comment: Hello, you need to prepare a html for your lightbox (popup) then you can control it's visibility using javascript.

Comment: do you currently have an lightbox? - if you do, could you provide the code for that?

Answer (score 0):

So this is a multi-step process. You first need to prevent the default behavior of the browser (to not open the link), then you need to create and insert your Lightbox-DOM-Elements (ie. the Img-tag) into your page and last you have to style it.

First the js:

```js
//Get all images with the class "magnific-popup"
 const allImagesWithLightbox = document.querySelectorAll("a.magnific-popup")

//Do the following for every found image:

Array.from(allImagesWithLightbox).forEach(image => {
let currentImageUrl= image.href;
  image.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
     event.preventDefault()
     let lightbox = document.createElement("div");
     let lightboxImage = document.createElement("img");
     lightboxImage.src = currentImageUrl;
     lightbox.classList.add("lightbox");
     lightbox.appendChild(lightboxImage);
     document.body.appendChild(lightbox);
  })
})
```

Now we're creating on click a lightbox-element for every image/link.

You should style it with css to make it absolute and centered etc.

Answer (score -1):

[glightbox](https://biati-digital.github.io/glightbox/) is a lightweight vanilla javascript lightbox which you can use for this purpose.

Documentation for it can be found [here](https://github.com/biati-digital/glightbox)